# What is the mechanism that dihydrolipoic acid undergoes to be oxidized by FAD?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, biochemistry, enzymes

The mechanism for dihydrolipoic acid oxidation in the pyruvate hydrogenase complex is not clearly demonstrated in any Lehninger textbook, other than the fact that FAD becomes FADH2. I am wondering what intermediates the FAD/FADH2 undergoes, my textbook just does skips over the details.

In the diagram below, the mechanisms are mostly all clear, except for the arrow I've highlighted with orange.

[image]

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47375/why-cant-electrons-be-transferred-using-hydrogen-ions

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. Let's look at the overall reaction first:

[image]

This reaction is catalysed by the dihydrolipoamide dehydrogenase in 6 steps and as you see from the schematic below (ref.1) the mechanism involves also four aminoacids near the active site (Cys48, Cys43, Hys451, and Glu456):

[image: 1)]

**References:**

1.https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780080453828001374

First image attribuition: By Jkallini - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=24958884

Comment: The redox steps are hydride transfers, i.e. hydrogen with two electrons. A description of the structural aspects is [here](https://proteopedia.org/wiki/index.php/Lipoamide_dehydrogenase).